# Show FlatList in React Native from a particular item index

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I show (automatically scroll) in a FlatList of a known item index when I go from one screen to another screen with list. For example, on the first screen I already know the item, and when I go to the next screen I want to show the list from the place where this item is located. But not to loose items above this known item.

I have tried:
initialScrollIndex without onScrollToIndexFailed (and it somehow worked but with errors)
then I added onScrollToIndexFailed and it doesn't work properly.

```
//For initialScrollIndex
const index = projects.findIndex(object => {
    if (selectedProject.id !== -1) {
      return object.projectId === selectedProject.id;
    }
  });

//For onScrollToIndexFailed
  const goToIndex = React.useCallback(info => {
    const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    wait.then(() => {
      flatList.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: info, animated: true });
    })
  }, []);
```

Comment: React Native Shared Element Transition

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some code

Comment: Tim I have edited my question